# tar archive without metadata

Tags: linux, md5, tar, file-attributes

Simple example:

```
tar cf <archive_name> <file_name>
md5sum <archive_name>
touch <file_name>
tar cf <archive_name> <file_name>
md5sum <archive_name>
```

Results of md5sum are different.

How to avoid this?

Comment: Interesting, since tar does it's best to keep things as they are.  I found this https://wiki.debian.org/ReproducibleBuilds/TimestampsInTarball which might help but I can't test since the option is not available in Mac OS X and I don't have access to a Linux box right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only different modify times (not access or change) cause this issue.
As workaround: use --mtime to override file modify times with one predefined timestamp.